# Stuck in T-SQL : XML to temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, xpath

I have a little challenge where I am currently stuck in.

This is my query:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml =
'<beginmsg>
  <refmsg>A1234567</refmsg>
  <shipments>
    <shipment>
      <load>
        <address>
          <name>Loadname</name>
          <street>Street</street>
          <zipcode>ABCDE</zipcode>
          <city>Munchen</city>
          <countrycode>DE</countrycode>
        </address>
        <dateTime>
          <date>2021-02-02</date>
          <timeFrom>08:00:00</timeFrom>
        </dateTime>
      </load>
      <unload>
        <address>
          <name>unloadname</name>
          <street>Street unload</street>
          <zipcode>1111</zipcode>
          <city>Dresden</city>
          <countrycode>DE</countrycode>
        </address>
      </unload>
      <goods>
        <good>
          <description>Cookies</description>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </good>
        <good>
          <description>Cookies</description>
          <quantity>3</quantity>
        </good>
        <good>
          <description>Some food</description>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </good>
      </goods>
      <barcodes>
        <barcode>7829348742910092309325</barcode>
        <barcode>7829348742112344114414</barcode>
        <barcode>0984746166149566188446</barcode>
      </barcodes>
      <references>
        <reference>GBP-4362</reference>
      </references>
    </shipment>
    <shipment>
      <load>
        <address>
          <name>shipment 2 load</name>
          <street>Street load2</street>
          <zipcode>1234 RR</zipcode>
          <city>Koln</city>
          <countrycode>DE</countrycode>
        </address>
        <dateTime>
          <date>2021-03-03</date>
          <timeFrom>10:00:00</timeFrom>
        </dateTime>
      </load>
      <unload>
        <address>
          <name>Shipment 2 unload</name>
          <street>Street 2 unl</street>
          <zipcode>1000 AA</zipcode>
          <city>Amsterdam</city>
          <countrycode>NL</countrycode>
        </address>
      </unload>
      <goods>
        <good>
          <description>Televisions</description>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </good>
      </goods>
      <barcodes>
        <barcode>0984746166149566188446</barcode>
      </barcodes>
      <references>
        <reference>HBR-7211CX</reference>
      </references>
    </shipment>
  </shipments>
</beginmsg>'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Goods') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Goods;

CREATE TABLE #Goods 
(
    row INT,
    shipmentreference VARCHAR(100),
    description VARCHAR(MAX),
    quantity INT,
    barcode VARCHAR(MAX)
);


INSERT INTO #Goods
    SELECT 
        "row" = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipment.shipment ORDER BY shipment.shipment),
        "shipmentreference" = CAST(shipment.shipment.value('(references/reference)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipment.shipment ORDER BY shipment.shipment) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
        "description" = goods.goods.value('(description)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
        "quantity" = goods.goods.value('(quantity)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
        "barcode" = barcode.barcode.value('(barcode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('beginmsg/shipments/shipment') shipment(shipment)
CROSS APPLY 
    shipment.shipment.nodes('goods/good') goods(goods)
CROSS APPLY 
    shipment.shipment.nodes('barcodes') barcode(barcode)

SELECT * FROM #Goods
```

The XML contains 2 shipments.

In the 1st shipment there are 3 goods segment with each 1 'good' segment. In the 2nd shipment there is one good segment.

I would like to merge each good, with their information and with the 1st barcode for the 1st good, 2nd barcode for the 2nd good etc. etc.
So I was thinking to create a TEMP table #goods and a temp table to store the barcodes in. In both temp tables I would like to add the "reference" so I can join both tables on that unique field.

But at this moment I am stuck. In my final query (as shown above) the output is as follow:

| row | reference | description | quantity | barcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GBP-4362-1 | Cookies | 1 | 7829348742910092309325 |
| 2 | GBP-4362-1 | Cookies | 3 | 7829348742910092309325 |
| 3 | GBP-4362-1 | Some food | 2 | 7829348742910092309325 |
| 1 | HBR-7211CX-1 | Television | 2 | 0984746166149566188446 |

So the barcode is each first (what is actually what I am querying :))

How can I iterate through these barcodes nodes and how can I manage to merge it into the row?

Comment: Please show us the expected output?